# Numero par entre 50 y 100 en php

Tags: php

Estoy intentando que me muestre por pantalla dado un número par comprendido entre 50 y 100 en PHP, si introduzco el numero par me lo da correcto pero en bucle.

Primero solicito el numero, luego llamo a las dos funciones, una me comprueba si es par, y la otra si esta dentro de el rango de 50 a 100. Quiero que mientras no sea par, siga pidiendo por pantalla el numero, cuando sea par muestre solo el resultado por pantalla

```php
    <form method="post" action="">
        Introduce un número par: <input type="number" name="numero" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>

    <?php

    function Par($numer) : bool {
        return $numer%2==0;
    }

    function Comprendido($numer): bool{
        return $numer>50 && $numer<100;
    }

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $numero = intval( $_POST["numero"]);

        $salir=false;

        while (!$salir ) {
            if(Comprendido($numero) && Par($numero)){
                for ($i = $numero; $i <= 100; $i += 2) {
                    echo $i . " ";
                }
                $salir=true;
            }else{

                echo "El número que ha introducido es incorrecto. Introduce un numero par comprendido entre 50 y 100";
                echo '
                <form method="post" action="">
                Introduce un número par: <input type="number" name="numero" required>
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
            </form>
                ';
            }
         
        }
      
     
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: y cual es el problema???

Comment: En mi humilde opinión, sería práctico usar JavaScript para hacerlo también, y luego hacerlo en PHP también. Ya que, cuando envías la solicitud al servidor sin validarla, eso hará que en producción gastes más recursos, y por ende en algunos casos más costos. Pero la decisión es tuya, es solo mi opinión.

Comment: @RodrigoRamírez No creo que tenga que preocuparse mucho por los recursos gastados en producción cuando está aprendiendo a programar, tampoco nos pasemos con las exigencias :)

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que tu error es "conceptual" por decirlo de alguna manera. Tu código podría funcionar si fuera una aplicación de consola, ahí es habitual tener un bucle para que la consola no cierre. Pero acá estas en el mundo web, hay solicitudes (request) y respuestas (response), por lo que el `while` no tiene sentido.

Es decir, el proceso es: El usuario envía una petición que incluye un número, el servidor procesa esta petición y devuelve una respuesta, esta respuesta avisa si el número cumple (o no) las condiciones asignadas. Si tu pones un bucle de la manera que lo estas haciendo, jamás saldrá del bucle, porque la respuesta nunca terminará de procesarse

```
<form method="post" action="">
    Introduce un número par: <input type="number" name="numero" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>

<?php

function Par($numer) : bool {
    return $numer%2==0;
}

function Comprendido($numer): bool{
    return $numer>50 && $numer<100;
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $numero = intval( $_POST["numero"]);

    if(Comprendido($numero) && Par($numero)){
        echo "El número ".$numero." es correcto";
    }
    else{
        echo "El número que ha introducido es incorrecto. Introduce un numero par comprendido entre 50 y 100";
    }
}
?>
```